# My custom theorem/proof environments aren't playing well together

Tags: spacing, environments, theorems

As can be shown in the following MWE, when I have a `theorem` environment followed by a `proof` environment, the proof isn't going into the next line; it's rendering right on top of the text I have for the theorem.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}

\newcounter{theorem}
\setcounter{theorem}{0}
\def\thetheorem{\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}

\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{theorem}
  \vspace{5mm}
  \makebox[-15pt][r]{
    \normalfont\large\color{cyan} Theorem\ \thetheorem$\;\;\;\;$}\setbox0\hbox{\ }
    \hspace{-\the\wd0}
    \ifx\relax#1\relax \else{\large\color{cyan} #1\\[1mm]}\fi
  }
  {\ignorespacesafterend\medskip}%

\newcounter{example}
\setcounter{example}{0}
\def\theexample{\thesection.\arabic{example}}

\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{example}
  \vspace{5mm}
  \makebox[-15pt][r]{
    \normalfont\large\color{cyan} Example\ \theexample$\;\;\;\;$}\setbox0\hbox{\ }
    \hspace{-\the\wd0}
    \ifx\relax#1\relax \else{\large\color{cyan} #1\\[1mm]}\fi
  }
  {\ignorespacesafterend\medskip}%

\newenvironment{proof}{%
  \vspace{5mm}
  \makebox[-15pt][r]{
    \normalfont\large\color{cyan} Proof$\;\;\;\;$}\setbox0\hbox{\ }
    \hspace{-\the\wd0}
  }
  {\ignorespacesafterend\medskip}%

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}
    asdf
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{proof}
    fdsa
  \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ignorespacesafterend` should always be last; and it doesn't matter if you end the paragraph at the environment end. Say `\newcounter{theorem}[section]` if you want that the counter is reset to zero in new sections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\medskip` and friends don't work in horizontal mode. Put a `\par` (or a `\\`) in the environment closure. (And then play with horizontal spacing ;-)

Comment: `\par` did it.. Thank you very much!

Comment: `\medskip` does indeed force a `\par`; it's `\vspace` that doesn't.

Comment: @egreg It does in plain TeX; in LaTeX, not.  ?!?  Checked `bla\medskip bla`on three computers ;-)

Comment: @SašoŽivanović You're right; I was thinking to a different thing.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing many things in a complicated way and so have very bad control of spaces. Here's a proposal for a better realization.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newcounter{theorem}[section]
\def\thetheorem{\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}

\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{%
  \par\addvspace{5mm}%
  \refstepcounter{theorem}%
  \noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \normalfont{\large\color{cyan}Theorem\ \thetheorem}\quad}%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax \else{\large\color{cyan}#1\\[1mm]}\fi
  \ignorespaces}
  {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\def\theexample{\thesection.\arabic{example}}

\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
  \par\addvspace{5mm}%
  \refstepcounter{example}%
  \noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \normalfont{\large\color{cyan}Example\ \theexample}\quad}%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax\else{\large\color{cyan}#1\\[1mm]}\fi
  \ignorespaces}
  {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\newenvironment{proof}{%
  \par\addvspace{5mm}
  \noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \normalfont{\large\color{cyan}Proof}\quad}%
  \ignorespaces}
  {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

1. Use `\newcounter{theorem}[section]` in order to reset the counter at each section.
2. Use `\par\addvspace{5mm}` so that this won't add space in excess when following other environments that use the same command (such as lists).
3. With `\noindent` you can control precisely where your label will go. Don't forget `\ignorespaces` at the end of the "begin part"
4. `\ignorespacesafterend` is useless in the "end part" since you force a paragraph end; in any case this must be the *last* token.
5. Be careful with spurious spaces in your definition. I've protected with `%` more end-of-lines than necessary, but better be safe than sorry.

[image]